# How to set the affinity of a task on a single core of multi-core GPGPU (Android)

Tags: android, opencl, gpu, gpgpu

Force execution of a task on selected CPU core can be done By (In android)

adb shell setprop debug.rs.default-CPU-driver 1

Is it possible to do with GPGPU (Mali TP 604)?

Comment: Depending on the driver version you may not have CPU support for OpenCL. Anyway, what you need is device fission, and you need CL1.2 for that, which ARM does not support yet.

Comment: I am able to do it on CPU. Want to do it on GPU So is it possible to do with CL1.1?